What is the most efficient way of getting an empty array in C# in terms of time and space?
let's say I need an empty array of a Book class in C#.
public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
}

I found the following 3 options to achieve this:

new Book[0]
Array.Empty<Book>()
ArraySegment<Book>.Empty

Can you suggest which one I should go for and the difference between them, please?

Can you please define "best"? For example somebody can think that ArraySegment<Book>.Empty is the best since it has more symbols and the person is paid by this metric =)

It seems like you haven't found [] yet.

@GuruStron you mean global::System.ArraySegment<Book>.Empty, surely ;p

@GuruStron By "best" I meant "best practice". But thank you for your comment.

You need to provide objective criteria by which the options can be evaluated.  Do not ask for best practice.  Your use of the word "suggest" pushes this even further towards seeking an opinion.  Also - you probably wanted to say string Author for the example.  I suggest beginning by evaluating the IL generated by each of your options.  You can do so at https://dotnetfiddle.net/

In most cases you would use Array.Empty<Book>(). Note that this will return the same instance each time it is called.
new Book[0] will produce a new array. This will require a new object to be allocated, but could be used if you want your array to compare differently to other empty arrays.
ArraySegment<Book>.Empty does not produce an array, but an ArraySegment. ArraySegment is typically used to represent a smaller section of an array. If you should use an ArraySegment or an Array is a more complicated question, especially since there are a wide variety of other collection types to chose between.

Thank you for answering my question even though its wording was a little bit awkward.

Book[] arr = [];

and let the compiler worry about it. Behind the scenes this will use Array.Empty<Book>(), which is a shared empty array of type Book. By contrast, new Book[0] allocates a new empty array every time, which is unnecessary allocation - there's no shared-state problem in a zero-length array.

Mind: That's only available starting at C# 12 (?), right?

@Fildor yes, you're right - so: build SDK 8 or later; note that the build SDK is not the same as the target platform, so this does not (quite) mean ".NET 8 or later" - you can <LangVersion> your way to []
